# Play video in reverse using AVPlayer and Swift on IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, video, reverse, avplayer

I have a recorded video clip that I want to play in reverse.

Playing forward is fine but as soon as I seek to the end of the video file and set the rate of playback to -1.0 the video clip seeks to the end of the clip (I see this in the timeline bar above the video) but does not play in reverse.

After I present the player view controller I check if it is ready to use:

```
            print("readyForDisplay = \(playerViewController.readyForDisplay)")
```

This tells me that all is ready to prepare to play.

I check if reverse play is possible:

```
let reversePlay = playerViewController.player!.currentItem?.canPlayReverse
        print("reversePlay = \(reversePlay)")
```

This returns TRUE

I then seek to the end of the clip and set the play back rate to -1.0 for reverse play.

```
playerViewController.player!.seekToTime(playerViewController.player!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
        playerViewController.player!.rate = -1.0
```

I believe having got this far it is ready to play because if I add the following:

```
let status : AVPlayerItemStatus? = playerViewController.player!.currentItem?.status

        if status == AVPlayerItemStatus.ReadyToPlay {
            print("Ready to play")
        }
```

It shows me that the clip is ready to play, so I am assuming that seeking to the end of clip (which is only 2 seconds long) has completed.

I then play the clip:

```
            playerViewController.player!.play()
```

It plays fine if I don't seek to the end and attempt to change the rate to set it to reverse play.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it somehow immediately dismissing because of being at the end? Did you try `seekToTime` to a spot in the middle? If that's the problem, you could set it to 1-2 seconds from the end.

Comment: @Headstock67 be aware that after checking canPlayReverse and seting playback rate to -1 you need to use reversePlaybackEndTime to check the end time

Comment: Thanks Tim for the suggestions. I used seekToTime to middle of the video clip. When played it jumped to the middle and then continued to play forward. So setting the playback rate to -1.0 doesn't seem to force reverse playback.

Comment: Leo, thanks for your tip. I wasn't entirely sure what you meant by 'check the end time' I went through Apple docs and it states that reversePlaybackEndTime defaults to kCMTimeInvalid and that in this case the effective time for reverse playback is kCMTimeZero, which I understand is a constant holding the video start point.To be sure it was targeting the start of the video I tried setting reversePlaybackEndTime to kCMTimeZero, after setting the rate to -1.0, but this made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to add some logging after launching the video and found that the rate was -1 before launching and 1 immediately after so it seems that the rate is reset to 1.

Could this be a bug?

Anyway setting the rate immediately after the request to play the video has the desire effect.

Comment: That's because the documentation of the play() method says: "Calling this method is the same as setting the rate to 1.0."