# How to play video in reverse in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a recorded in my app video that I want to play in reverse. I use local url for playing in AVPlayer. I found other questions where authors say they check

```
let canPlayReverse = playViewController.player!.currentItem!.canPlayReverse
```

And it returns them **true** and they just set

```
player.rate = -1.0
```

But in my case it returns **false** and it doesn't work

Comment: have you said .play() first? Have you tried setting the video currentTime to the end first ?

Comment: please reference this url  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902203/reverse-video-playback-in-ios

Comment: @SeanLintern88 yes , I tried .play() before and after it. How to do that?

Comment: @BhupatBheda thanks

Comment: seekToTime on the .item

Comment: Yes I have tried .seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

Comment: Is it working properly @VikaGrinyuk

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have seeked to the time `kCMTimeZero`, which is the beginning of the video. If you play, it doesn't play anything as there is nothing to play **before** that point. So, seek to the end of the clip:

```
.seek(to: playerViewController.player!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
```

and it should work correctly.

Comment: Oh thank you. It displays the last frame, but when I start to play it, it doesn't play.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948500/play-video-in-reverse-using-avplayer-and-swift-on-ios-9

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to reverse video

```
   let duratTime: CMTime = (player.currentItem?.asset.duration)!
    if CMTIME_IS_VALID(duratTime) {
        player.seek(to: duratTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
        player.rate = -1
    }
    else {
        print("In valid time")
    }
```

Comment: Nice approach :) But with remote videos there are lack in playback. So it will be necessary a cache download function to play it locally first.